# issue with calculation function c++

Tags: c++

my program is a simple payroll calculator.

if the employee type is 0 any hours worked over 40 are time and a half.
if type is 1 they don't get overtime just straight pay.

I am trying to hold all the data in struct arrays. This is a homework assignment, and my program meets the requirements, but the issue im having is after i input hours for employees and then choose menu option c, my output is just zero.

Im not sure why exactly there wasn't any data outputted except zero in the column. I have no errors in my compiler.

What did I do wrong?

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


//*********************************************************************************************
//         Structure to hold employee ID, Name, Pay rate per hour, Employee type
//*********************************************************************************************

struct employeeRecord {
    int IDnum;    // holds employee id number
    string name;    // holds employess name
    float payRate;    // holds employee pay rate
    int empType;    // holds employee type
};

//*********************************************************************************************
//                         structure to hold time sheet
//*********************************************************************************************

struct timeSheet{
    float hours;    //hours worked
    float grossPay;    // gross pay
    float netPay;    // net pay
    float taxAmount;    // tax amount deduction
};

//*********************************************************************************************
//                               function prototype
//*********************************************************************************************
void addEmployee(employeeRecord *employee, int &index);
void addTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index);
void calcTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index, float taxRate);
void outTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index);


//*********************************************************************************************
//                                 main function
//*********************************************************************************************

int main(){


    float taxRate = .15;    // taxrate on pay
    char choice;    // holds user choice option
    int index = 0; // index of array

    // create struct arrays to hold data
    employeeRecord employee[2];
    timeSheet time[2];

    // menu title
    cout << "\nArmadillo Automotive Group Payroll\n" << endl;

//*********************************************************************************************
//               do loop to cycle through menu options & validate input
//*********************************************************************************************
    do{
        //menu
        cout << "\nMenu Options: \n";
        cout << "A - Add Employee" << endl;
        cout << "B - Add Employee's Hours" << endl;
        cout << "C - Print Payroll Report" << endl;

        //take user menu choice
        cout << "\nEnter Menu Option: ";
        cin >> choice;
        choice = tolower(choice);

        //validate user selection
        while (choice != 'a' && choice != 'b' && choice!= 'c'){
            cout << "Please enter 'A' 'B' or 'C' : ";
            cin >> choice;
        }

        // Process menu selection choice
        if (choice != 'c'){
            if (choice == 'a'){
                //process new employee
                if (index < 2){
                    addEmployee(employee, index);
                }

                else{
                    cout << "\nEmployee index full" << endl;
                }
            }
            // if choice 'b' add employee work hours
            else{
                addTime(time, employee, index);
            }


        }   

    }while (choice != 'c');

    // calculates and stores employees time sheet information in struct array
    calcTime(time, employee, index, taxRate);

    //display pay check outputs
    outTime(time, employee, index);

    return 0;
}




//*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to add employee to index
//*********************************************************************************************
void addEmployee(employeeRecord *employee, int &index){
    //take employees ID #
    cout << "\nEnter employee's ID number: ";
    cin >> employee[index].IDnum;

    //validate employee id # is greater than 0
    while (employee[index].IDnum < 0){
        cout << "\nPlease enter an ID # above 0 : ";
        cin >> employee[index].IDnum;
    }

    //take employees name
    cout << "\nEnter employee's Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, employee[index].name);

    //validate line has characters only
    //**********************
    //**********************
    //**********************

    //take employees payrate
    cout << "\nEnter employee's pay rate: $";
    cin >> employee[index].payRate;

    //validate payrate is amount above 0
    while(employee[index].payRate < 0){
    cout << "\nPlease enter a value greater than 0: ";
    cin >> employee[index].payRate;
    }

    // take employees emptype
    cout << "\nEnter Employee type \n";
    cout << "0 for union, 1 for management: ";
    cin >> employee[index].empType;

    //validate 0 or 1 was entered
    while(employee[index].empType != 0 && employee[index].empType != 1){
    cout << "Enter 1 or 0: ";
    cin >> employee[index].empType;
    }

    // increment index for future entry
    index++;
}

//*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to add time to an employee
//*********************************************************************************************

void addTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index){

    //set index to zero to start with first employee on list
    index = 0;
    //main instruction
    cout << "Enter timecard information for each employee: " << endl;

    //enter hours for each employee for loop
    for(int i=0; i < 2; i++){
    cout << "Hours worked for " << employee[index].name << ": ";
    cin >> time[index].hours;
    index++;}
}

//*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to to calculate timesheet
//*********************************************************************************************

void calcTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index, float taxRate){
    index = 0;    // set index back to zero to start at first array index
    float tempHours;    //temp hour hold
    float overTime;    // overTime hours
    float hours = time[index].hours;    //hours worked 
    float grossPay = time[index].grossPay;    //employes's gross pay
    float netPay = time[index].netPay;    //employes's net pay
    float taxAmount = time[index].taxAmount;    ////employes's tax deduction
    int empType = employee[index].empType;    // employee type
    float payRate = employee[index].payRate;    // employes pay rate

    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++){
        if (empType == 0){
            if(hours > 40){
                tempHours = 40;
                overTime = hours - 40;
                grossPay = (overTime * (payRate * 1.5)) + (tempHours * payRate);
                taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
                netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
            }
            else{
                grossPay = hours * payRate;
                taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
                netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
            }
        }
        else{
            grossPay = hours * payRate;
            taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
            netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
        }

        // increase index number
        index++;

    }
}

//*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to to print out timesheet
//*********************************************************************************************

void outTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index){
    index = 0;    // set index back to zero to start at first array index
    int empID = employee[index].IDnum;    //employes id number
    string name = employee[index].name;    // employees name
    float grossPay = time[index].grossPay;    //employes's gross pay
    float taxAmount = time[index].taxAmount;    ////employes's tax deduction
    float netPay = time[index].netPay;    //employes's net pay

    cout << "Pay Roll Report\n" << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "ID" << setw(30) << left << "Name";
    cout << setw(10) << right << "Gross Pay" << setw(10) << right << "Tax";
    cout << setw(10) << right << "Net Pay" << endl;

    // for loop to display employee information.'
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++){
    cout << setw(10) << left << empID << setw(30) << left << name;
    cout << setw(10) << right << grossPay << setw(10) << right << taxAmount;
    cout << setw(10) << right << netPay << endl;
    index++;}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to look over our [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the page on [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This isn't just to make our jobs easier (which will entice more of us to try to help you), it's a vital coding skill in its own right. What did you do wrong? You wrote too much code without testing it, and now the part that's malfunctioning is entangled with a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: Did you step through your code using your compiler's debugger, yet? If not, why not?

Comment: You need to seriously rethink the `addTime` function and how it works.